# Functions generating prime numbers in math packages

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, mathematica

Does anyone have an idea on how prime number generating functions such as Prime[n] in Mathematica generate the $n^{th}$ prime number?

Comment: [link](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/25809/how-does-mathematica-calculate-the-nth-prime)  See that link for the answer.  You'd be better off asking on the mathematica stack exchange also.